# Print current date to csv with bash

Tags: bash, date, csv, printf

I'm having the hardest time trying to do the most simple thing. I want to print the current date with Year-month-day-hour-minute-seconds to a .csv file

I want the formatting of the .csv file to look like this:

```
Year    Month    Day    Hour    Minute    Second
2017    03       08     17      52        23
```

And i cannot figure out for the life of me what to do. I have tried figuring it out with printf and using "," as the delimiter but the formatting will not work. It does not end up in the columns like i want.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple `date` formatting problem. Try the following :

```
echo "Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second" && date +"%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S" > myfile.csv
```

Here is [a link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/) to `date` formatting syntax.